# Contar itens com uma determinada extensão dentro de um array em PHP

Tags: php, array

Olá, bom dia! Tudo bom?
  Preciso montar uma galeria de midias para um determinada extensão de imagens ('.jpg') e estou com dificuldade para realizar a contagem dos arquivos ($key) no campo valor (ds_midia_link).
  Como devo proceder?

Desde já agradeço,

[midias] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [midia] => Array
                (
                    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [id_imagem] => 5a29842d8ec9f
                            [ds_imagem_credi] => Google
                            [ds_imagem] => Pantera Negra
                            [ds_imagem_link] => http://portal.interno.com.br//_midias/jpg/exemplo.jpg

```
                [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                        [id_imagem] => 5a29842d8ec9f
                        [ds_imagem_credi] => Google
                        [ds_imagem] => Pantera 
                        [ds_imagem_link] => http://portal.interno.com.br//_midias/jpg/exemplo1.jpg

                [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                        [id_imagem] => 5a29842d8ec9f
                        [ds_imagem_credi] => Google
                        [ds_imagem] => Pantera 
                        [ds_imagem_link] => http://portal.interno.com.br//_midias/jpg/exemplo2.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

Existe uma função no php que faz a contagem `count()`. Atribua o valor a uma variável por exemplo `$qtdReg = count($seuArray);`

Ref: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.count.php

```
<?php

$arr = [
        [
            'id_imagem' => '5a29842d8ec9f',
            'ds_imagem_credi' => 'Google',
            'ds_imagem' => 'Pantera',
            'ds_imagem_link' => 'http://portal.interno.com.br//_midias/jpg/exemplo1.jpg'
        ],
        [
            'id_imagem' => '5a29842d8ec9f',
            'ds_imagem_credi' => 'Google',
            'ds_imagem' => 'Pantera',
            'ds_imagem_link' => 'http://portal.interno.com.br//_midias/jpg/exemplo2.jpg'
        ],
];

$qtdReg = count($arr);

echo $qtdReg;
```

A saída será: 2

Comment: Entendi. O problema é que o meu array eu posso ter midias do tipo imagem com outra extensão (ex. png, gif, etc)... teria como eu refinar pela extensão do arquivo?

Comment: Ai você terá que percorrer o array de um exemplo melhor então, tipo você vai ter alguma key no array que vai ser extensão?

Comment: Eu precisaria chegar no $value da $key ['ds_imagem_link'] percorrer todo ele e verificar se ele possui determinada extensão...